# Problem With Routing On Two Default Gateways

Tags: linux, routes, debian, ping, gateway

I have setup a box/small server with three interfaces. One interface leads to an internal net and owns a default route in routing table rt1. Another interface is connected to a Fritz!Box and leads into the internet and also has a default route in routing table rt2.

I have put up two default gateways (table rt1 and rt2) and now I want to ping something in the internet on a certain interface (eth0.103), which leads to the Fritz!Box (and the internet), or even on both, but that does not work, although traceroute and even an SSH connection are working on this interface. I mean, I can even contact/connect to that box (eth0.103) from outside/over the Fritz!Box/internet. Also, on eth0.101 there is no routing or pinging happening.

The Fritz!Box has the address 192.168.178.1 and eth0.103 (192.168.178.20) is connected to it directly.

command

```
ping -I eth0.103 8.8.8.8
ping -I eth0.101 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1 rt1
2 rt2
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0.101
    iface eth0.101 inet static
    address 172.19.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip route add 172.19.2.0/24 dev eth0.101 src 172.19.2.2 table rt1
    post-up ip route add default via 172.19.2.1 dev eth0.101 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add from 172.19.2.2/32 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add to 172.19.2.2/32 table rt1

auto eth0.102
    iface eth0.102 inet manual

auto eth0.103
    iface eth0.103 inet static
    address 192.168.178.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0.103 src 192.168.178.20 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0.103 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add from 192.168.178.20/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 192.168.178.20/32 table rt2

auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0.102 wlan0
    bridge_waitport 0
    address 192.168.1.254
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

ip route show

```
172.19.2.0/24 dev eth0.101  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.19.2.2
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.254 
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0.103  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.20
```

ip route show table rt1

```
default via 172.19.2.1 dev eth0.101 
172.19.2.0/24 dev eth0.101  scope link  src 172.19.2.2
```

ip route show table rt2

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0.103 
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0.103  scope link  src 192.168.178.20
```

I cannot figure out, if I did something wrong with those gateways or the routing rules/tables maybe. Also, I find it weird, that I can connect over the Fritz!Box's public IP address to the server, while pinging from it does not work. Thank you in advance, guys.

Comment: Btw, getting a down-vote because of using "Debian" in the title is not a nice thing. A comment or anything would have been more helpful. I did not know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with a lot of googling and reading on Linux sites and here in Stack Overflow I found the solution.

The routing tables were fine, but somehow not transmitting the default gateways to the main table. Therefore I could not ping or achieve anything, but still traceroute was working. Even static routes were working.

So, I added those two important lines (with the metric values) in /etc/network/interfaces and now the default gateways of both routing tables are transmitted to the main routing table.

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
101 rt1
102 rt2
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0.101
    iface eth0.101 inet static
    address 172.19.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip route add 172.19.2.0/24 dev eth0.101 src 172.19.2.2 table rt1
    post-up ip route add default via 172.19.2.1 dev eth0.101 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add from 172.19.2.2/32 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add to 172.19.2.2/32 table rt1
    post-up ip route add default via 172.19.2.1 metric 100 dev eth0.101
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt1
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt1

auto eth0.102
    iface eth0.102 inet manual

auto eth0.103
    iface eth0.103 inet static
    address 192.168.178.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0.103 src 192.168.178.20 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0.103 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add from 192.168.178.20/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 192.168.178.20/32 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.178.1 metric 101 dev eth0.103
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt2
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt2

auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0.102 wlan0
    bridge_waitport 0
    address 192.168.1.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```